# Botton ease-out transparent transition

Tags: html, css, button, css-transitions

I added a hover effect to my button. The idea was to make the button background transparent (in an ease-out effect) when someone hover over the button. The problem is that I can not make it transparent...

I used ease-in beacause of the direction.

my code;

```
<div class="container">
<button class="btn-1">Get in Touch</button>
</div>
```

CSS;

```
.container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   text-align: center;
 }

.btn-1{
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   border: none;
   color: white;
   background-color: rgb(25, 62, 148);
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   transition: ease-in 0.3s;
   font-size: 2rem;
   outline: none;
 }

 .btn-1:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 300px 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `transition` property takes in the `property-name` that needs to be changed on the triggering event, as its first parameter. The code has been updated for better understanding and comments have been added.

I have added `all` in the example, which means it will add transition to all the properties that are changing. One point to note here is the transition is applied only to the properties that are **quantitative** ie those can be measures.

```css
.container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   text-align: center;
 }

.btn-1{
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   border: none;
   color: white;
   background-color: rgb(25, 62, 148);
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   transition: all ease-in 0.3s; /* We need to define the property for which we want the transition. Here I have used 'all' that applies to all the properties. You can use a specific property name as well. (eg background-color)*/
   font-size: 2rem;
   outline: none;
 }

 .btn-1:hover{
    background-color: rgb(25, 6, 18); /* We need to update the property that we want the changes to. */
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<button class="btn-1">Get in Touch</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

property requires the property to be transformed.

Comment: Thank you for the response, please see https://www.lovejoynumbers.com/ for the example. This is what is should be, but on my page there is a background image. that is the reason for a transparent backgorund inset of white or black. Please let me know if you can help me!